# ggplot2 and sf: coord_fixed() doesn't work combined with geom_sf() and coord_sf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I try to use `coord_fixed(ratio=5)` combined with `geom_sf()` and `coord_sf()`in ggplot without success. In my example:

```
#Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)

# Get data set - x any are the points
all.stands.predict<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/prediction_bronze_stink_bug.csv")

#Create a map
(sites <- st_as_sf(all.stands.predict, coords = c("x", "y"), 
                   crs = 4674, agr = "constant"))
gg <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=sites, color="red") +
  #coord_fixed(ratio = 5) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4674)) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "bl", which_north = "true", 
                         pad_x = unit(0.3, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.5, "in"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) + #Add a north arrow
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.55) + #Add a scale bar
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  theme_bw() 

# I inspected the map created
plot(gg)
```

[image: mymap]

If I remove `#` in `coord_fixed(ratio = 5) +` my output is always:

```
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

And no image in `ratio = 5` is created. Please, any ideas why?

Comment: You can only define one `coord_*()` for a given plot, and `geom_sf()` only works with `coord_sf()`.  This means your ratio must be defined in the `coord_sf()`.  Looks like you need to specify a different coordinate reference system `crs`, but I'm not sure how that is done and what to specify there.

Comment: You're basically talking about using a different map projection, which you can do through the `sf` package, but you're going to distort the representation of your data on the map.  [This link](https://pmarchand1.github.io/atelier_rgeo/rgeo_workshop.html) might be helpful for you to understand a bit what I mean.  If you want to stretch your image, you're changing the proportions and therefore the projection.

Comment: Thanks, @chemdork123, but my data set is always in crs = 4674 projection without transformation, my basic idea is just only to change the map ratio.

Comment: @Leprechault If you change the map ratio, it's not really a map anymore.  Since the data is fairly close to the equator, why don't you just plot it as x/y values rather than as an sf object?

Comment: That's just it - if you change the aspect ratio (i.e. how much distance in pixels corresponds to one unit in x vs. one unit in y), you change the projection.  If you want to view a larger x dimension, you should use `xlim()` and `ylim()` to indicate your desired limits.  In this case, just increase x axis if you want a "wider" image.  Your original axis goes from 52.327 to 52.324, so something like `xlim(52.33,52.32)` gives you a wider plot with the same aspect ratio.